# Free Madrid transit pass for 65+

Tags: tickets, public-transport, madrid, senior-travel

The [English version](https://www.metromadrid.es/en/descuentostemporales) of the Madrid transit agency page on passes suggests that senior citizens may be entitled to free transit (with a transit card of nominal cost).

> From 1 January 2023, people aged 65 and over in the Community of Madrid will be able to use a ticket free of charge to travel throughout the region.

The original [Spanish version](https://www.metromadrid.es/es/descuentostemporales), however, seems to me to state that this discount is only available to seniors *who reside in Madrid.*

> A partir del 1 de enero de 2023, las personas de 65 y más años de la Comunidad de Madrid podrán disponer de un título gratuito para efectuar sus desplazamientos por toda la región.

Preposition translation is always a messy business—here the issue is "de". Can a Madrileño confirm which reading is correct? Extra question: why is [www.esmadrid.com](http://www.esmadrid.com) unreachable for me?

Comment: The extra question is a bit off-topic here. But seems the website is somewhat unstable. It failed for me a few minutes ago, but works now.

Comment: The next paragraph says this "In order to benefit from the free fare, you must have a personal Public Transport Card on which you can load this new fare option that will give you access to our entire public transport network. You do not need to purchase a different card."  The website application form for a TPP seems to accept a passport as identification, but if one is a casual visitor getting a TPP seems to me just too much hassle. (BTW like you I thought the implication of the Spanish version was that this was for residents of the Community of Madrid only. But I wasn't sure.)